# Dependency inversion and device independent data

Tags: c++, c++11, inversion-of-control, device-driver, solid-principles

I'm working on an application, whose lowest layer is comprised of an input-output communication device (say a Serial Port).

In order to achieve a more valuable tool with minimal effort, the neighbouring layers should be unaffected by variations on the communication medium (for example Ethernet or USB). This claims, if i'm not wrong, the use of the Dependency Inversion Principle, among others. I have had a look on examples.

```
class DataIOClient
{   
public:
DataIOClient(void){}
~DataIOClient(void){}

virtual void WriteData(DataIOClientData* data) = 0;
virtual void ReadData(DataIOClientData* data) = 0;
};
```

This interface, along with its corresponding implementation (which will depend on the comm architecture selected) should decouple my upper layer from the comm layer.

However, I have come across with the problem of the initialization. As each of the architectures request different initialization parameters (9600 8N1 in COMPort or 192.168.1.2 in an Ethernet or LPT1 for parallel port comm, for example), I cannot figure out the dependency scheme or the underlying abstraction to make it feasible.

If DataIOClient "knew" a priori the input parameters that the implementation requests, it would be coupled and no dependency inversion anymore, am I correct? I have a fuzzy feeling that I'm not understanding correctly the proper application of this principle.

Thanks

Comment: You probably want a `virtual` destructor.

Comment: Pass the configuration in the constructor, or an object which will allow the client to retrieve the configuration from the environment (a context object).

Comment: @KerrekSB: I don't understand how a virtual destructor may help.

Comment: @PeterWood: I will have a look on the concept of context objects and how can I implement some kind of it.

Comment: @Manex I don't know what researching context objects will turn up; it's just a term I use. It's simply giving an object enough information to be able to configure itself. I looked it up and found [this on Ward's Wiki](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ContextObjectsAreEvil).

Answer (score 2):

Sounds to me like a textual configuration file along with parameters should work; you parse the configuration and call a suitable factory function:

**.config:**

```
IOClient = { type = "ethernet", config = { host = "12.34.56.78", port = "8080" } }

IOClient = { type = "usb", config = { } }

IOClient = { type = "serial", config = { device = "/dev/modem" } }
```

**creator.cc:**

```
item = read_tuple("IOClient");

std::unique_ptr<DataIOClient> = factory.create(item["type"], item["config"]);
```

Comment: Never heard about the factory pattern. However, unique_ptr is a cpp11 feature isn't it? I'll meditate on your answer to see if fresh ideas arrive.